# Determining feature dataset of feature class using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, feature-class, feature-dataset

Is there a way to check if a feature class full path string is a path to a feature class within a file geodatabase feature dataset in arcpy?

For example:

`C:\test\test.gdb\testdataset\featureclass`

I'd like to return `testdataset`.

I can't find it in any of the applicable `Describe` objects. I can do it with string manipulation...

```
fullpath = r"C:\test\test.gdb\testdataset\featureclass"
pathlen = len(fullpath.split (".gdb")[0]) + 4
namelen = len(fullpath.split ("\\")[-1])
dataset = fullpath[pathlen:-namelen].replace ("\\", "")
```

This seems like too much code though.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
>>> #testfc is a fc within a fd, as shown with this catalogPath statement:
>>> desc = arcpy.Describe('testfc')
>>> desc.catalogPath
    u'C:\\Users\\whitley-wayne\\Desktop\\data.gdb\\dataset1\\testfc'
>>>
>>> #this shows how to essentially use the Describe method twice to get the fd name:
>>> desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
>>> if hasattr(desc, 'path'):
...     descPth = arcpy.Describe(desc.path)
...     if hasattr(descPth, 'dataType'):
...         if descPth.dataType == 'FeatureDataset': 
...             print 'the feature dataset name: {0}'.format(descPth.name)
...             
    the feature dataset name: dataset1
>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use Describe on the feature class parent directory.

```
if arcpy.Describe(os.path.dirname(path_to_featureclass)).dataType == 'FeatureDataset': 
    do something...
else:
    do something else...
```

If you don't have the path already, you can get it with the catalogPath property:

```
arcpy.Describe(featureclass).catalogPath
```